# In VS Code, is it possible to programmatically open devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

In VS Code, you can use command palette to open dev tools

[image]

Is it possible to programmatically open it? I scanned through the [API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) but didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find it is open the keyboard shortcuts under preferences

[image]

So apparently the command is called `workbench.action.toggleDevTools` which you can execute as

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.toggleDevTools');
```

On Windows it's File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

On Mac it's Code->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

Of course you can also press Ctrl-Shift-P/Cmd-Shift-P and type "keyb" and it will show up.

[image]

Comment: How gman, may I ask how to open the "Keyboard Shortcuts" page showed in the screenshot? I tried very hard but still can't find it. Thanks.

Comment: The "Keyboard shortcuts reference" under "Help" would open an online pdf, and doesn't show the command id.